# Receiving multiple signals at the same frequency at the same time

Tags: radio, multiplexing

I'm doing a project for my school it's a communication platform for different mobile devices I'm gonna build and I need to send data from the devices to station am making, I figured how to use signal spreading to encode multiple signals and send it to multiple devices like a cell tower.

But what I wanna know is how the tower I'm building is gonna receive multiple signals and not cancel each other out?

Answer (score 1):

One basic concept is that if multiple signals are mutually orthogonal in some sense (time domain, frequency domain, encoding, spreading function, phase relationship, etc.) they won't interfere in that domain, and thus can't cancel.